# Нужна ли здесь запятая перед «или»?

Tags: пунктуация, запятые, союзы, или

*Важно формировать у людей внутренний контроль(,) **или** самоконтроль.*
Если запятая перед "или" нужна, то почему?

Comment: Эту проблему без помощи Автора решить не получится.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Правильно:  ***Важно формировать у людей внутренний контроль,** **или самоконтроль**.*

Здесь пояснительный союз ИЛИ, запятая ставится.

Сравнить: *Такой контроль мы называем внутренним контролем **или самоконтролем*** (разделительный союз ИЛИ, нет запятой).

**Пояснение**

1. Пояснительный союз ИЛИ применяется  **при лексическом тождестве** (два названия для одного предмета).  Например: *Кольчатый тюлень, **ИЛИ нерпа,** относится к отряду ластоногих.*  Запятая перед пояснительным союзом ИЛИ ставится.
2. Но здесь есть **интересная особенность**: мы считаем союз ИЛИ пояснительным, если используем его в речи именно в  значении тождества.
3. С другой стороны, при раскрытии этой темы может использоваться  **разделительный союз ИЛИ** (запятая не ставится):  *Такой тюлень называется кольчатым тюленем **или нерпой**.*

Здесь ключевым словом является глагол «называется»:  у нас есть два названия для этого животного и мы можем использовать одно название или другое.

4. Объяснение у  Розенталя:  http://old-rozental.ru/punctuatio.php?sid=119#pp119  пункт 2. Примечание.

**Примечания: 1.** Следует различать пояснительный союз или (в значении ‘то есть’, перед ним ставится запятая) и разделительный союз или (перед ним запятая не ставится, если союз не повторяется). Ср.: Флексия, или окончание, имеется только у слов, относящихся к изменяемым частям речи — повторить союз нельзя, его можно заменить союзом то есть; Изменяемая часть слова в конце его называется флексией или окончанием — здесь разделительный союз может быть повторен (…называется или флексией, или окончанием).

Comment: Уважаемый участник форума, минусовавший мой ответ. Я обращаюсь к вам с убедительной просьбой указать причину.   Как принято считать, на форуме мы делимся знаниями друг с другом,  а также с нашими гостями,  поэтому мне хотелось бы знать, в чем моя ошибка.  Это важно для меня. Если вы не исполните мою просьбу, то я больше не буду отвечать вообще.  Согласитесь,  что это в интересах всего общества, а не только лично меня. Ответы должны быть правильными, а ошибки следует обсуждать и исправлять.