# Запятая перед "или как?"

Tags: пунктуация

Ставится ли запятая перед "или как?"
А-ля:
Ты дурак или как?
Ты идти собираешься или как?
Я могу счесть твои слова комплиментом или как?

Comment: Предложу такой вариант: Ты, дурак или как?/Ты, идти собираешь или как? / Я могу счесть твои слова комплиментом? или как?( с такой орфографией, с маленькой буквы новое предложение)

Comment: Возможный дубликат вопроса: [Нужна ли здесь запятая перед «или»?](https://rus.stackexchange.com/questions/467828/%d0%9d%d1%83%d0%b6%d0%bd%d0%b0-%d0%bb%d0%b8-%d0%b7%d0%b4%d0%b5%d1%81%d1%8c-%d0%b7%d0%b0%d0%bf%d1%8f%d1%82%d0%b0%d1%8f-%d0%bf%d0%b5%d1%80%d0%b5%d0%b4-%d0%b8%d0%bb%d0%b8)

Comment: В той теме был пояснительный союз ИЛИ. а это разделительный

Answer (score 1):

(Ответ исправлен.)

Фраза известная, причем встречаются **обе формы** письма. И действительно, возможны оба варианта: постановка запятой и произношение с паузой; нет паузы и запятой.

(1) ***Ты дурак или кАк?*** Одно ударение, нет паузы

(2) ***Ты дурАк, или кАк?*** Два ударения, пауза.

2. Объяснение может быть разное. К примеру, будем считать, что «как» означает «как тебя понимать». Тогда это два предложения в составе ССП, причем второе предложение состоит только из союзного слова.

Запятую можно не ставить при общей вопросительной интонации. Но если сделать ударение на каждой части, то общая вопросительная интонация не будет учитываться.

3. Чем сложнее предложение, тем больше оснований разделить его на две части и **поставить запятую**.  Но все же многое зависит от авторского произношения: хочет ли автор подчеркнуть (выделить ударением)  первую часть. Например:

*Ты идти собираешься **или кАк?***

*Я могу счесть твои слова комплимЕнтом, **или кАк?***

Примечание. Решение в данном случае сходно с постановкой знаков для сочетания ***"и наоборот"***, где также предлагается два варианта.
[Справочник по пунктуации](http://new.gramota.ru/spravka/punctum?layout=item&id=58_237)

Comment: **Комментарии были [перемещены в чат](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/147933/discussion-on-answer-by-sharon----); пожалуйста, не продолжайте дискуссию здесь.** Прежде чем разместить комментарий ниже этого, пожалуйста, ознакомьтесь с [назначением комментариев](/help/privileges/comment). Комментарии, которые не запрашивают уточнения или не предлагают улучшения, скорее всего должны быть [ответами](/help/how-to-answer), размещены на [meta] или написаны в [chat]. Комментарии, продолжающие дискуссию, могут быть удалены.