# Бывает ли "или "присоединительным?

Tags: синтаксис

> "Ты адекватный (,) или как?"

Эту фразу можно вроде бы трактовать по-разному:

1)ты адекватный или не адекватный;

2)ты адекватный, ты нормален?

Может ли "или" быть союзом присоединительным?

Comment: Повтор вопроса  https://rus.stackexchange.com/questions/474809/Запятая-перед-или-как

Comment: И что с того, что можно трактовать "или" как присоединительное из контекста. Я могу сказать вам "да", что в контексте можно трактовать как "нет", и что после этого мы будем на полном серьезе обсуждать у "да" функцию отрицания? Ладно, с вами все понятно, ну вас в баню.